# Visual basic code to show dynamic date range change in SSRS report

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services

Hi I created a SSRS placeholder [Date] in one SSRS report.

```
Date Range: [Date]
```

And the expression of the placeholder is:

```
=Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(Parameters!start_date.Value, "Long Date") + " - " + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(Parameters!end_date.Value, "Long Date")
```

However, I set the start_date and the end_date default to Null. When I preview the report, this placeholder would show something like this:

```
Date Range: -
```

If I change the start date to 3/1/2020 and end date to 3/31/2020, then it will show:

```
Date Range: Sunday, March 1, 2020 - Tuesday, March 31, 2020
```

How can I change my expression to make the default Date Range to be from the oldest date to the latest date if any or both of them is/are Null? Here is my Visual Basic code, I tried my best but I did not have a lot of programming experience, so it may not be true:

```
=If start date is null 
then Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(min(Fields!arrival_date.Value), "Long Date") + " - " + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(Parameters!end_date.Value, "Long Date")
if end date is null
then Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(Parameters!start_date.Value, "Long Date") + " - " + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(max(Fields!arrival_date.Value), "Long Date")
if start date and end date is null
then Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(min(Fields!arrival_date.Value), "Long Date") + " - " + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(max(Fields!arrival_date.Value), "Long Date")
else Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(Parameters!start_date.Value, "Long Date") + " - " + Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.format(Parameters!end_date.Value, "Long Date")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need any VBA to accomplish this. The way I would do this is as follows.

Createa a report.

Add 2 parameters `StartDate` and `EndDate`

I would then create a dataset something like (taken from the sam,[le adventureworks database)

```
SELECT        CustomerID, OrderDate, SubTotal
FROM            Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE        (SubTotal < 100) -- just to reduce the sample data
and 
    (
        (OrderDate >= @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL)
    AND
        (OrderDate <= @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
    )
```

This will use the dates provided or is either are `NULL` it will resort us using the first or last record found.

Then for you place holders the [Start] placeholder would be something like.

```
=IIF(
    Parameters!StartDate.Value=Nothing
    ,First(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "DataSet1")
    , Parameters!StartDate.Value
    )
```

and in a similar fashion of the [End] placeholder

```
=IIF(
    Parameters!EndDate.Value=Nothing
    ,Last(Fields!OrderDate.Value, "DataSet1")
    , Parameters!EndDate.Value
    )
```

This will either show the selected start date parameter **or** the first record found if not parameter was specified and the same for the end date except if will show the last record found.

Finally I formatted the placeholders to show as long dates.

The results look like this with none, one and both parameters selected.

[image]

(actual data continues to be displayed up to 30th June 2014)
We how the first and last order date for the entire dataset as not parameters were specified.

[image]

Here the first order date after the 20th May 2011 is 1st July but the parameter date is shown as that is what the user selected

[image]

Finally the parameter dates are shown in both placeholders even though the data does not extend that far as that is what the user selected.

Comment: Thx. I get what you say.